# How does `get` work?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, database, get

I saw this:

```
get '/:key' do |key|
```

I want to know its use.

Comment: Are you sure that's Rails? Looks more like Sinatra to me.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like its making a GET request to the root_path and passing a parameter called key.

Answer (score -1):

I would recommend reading over this guide:  http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html.  It should be more than helpful in answering your question